# How can I replace the contents of a scrollable div without jumping to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with the `overflow: auto` style.  It is populated via AJAX with a result table.  The rows in this div are editable, and with each edit I refresh the contents.  The problem is, if the user edits something at the bottom of the div, the refresh brings them back to the top.

I had some luck using anchors with Firefox, but not all versions of IE jumped to the anchors within the div.

Is there any way to replace the contents of a div like this without having the scrollbar jump to the top?  Any other suggestions?  I like to refresh the entire set of results rather than just the updated row if possible, but if there are no workarounds I guess I will pursue that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you change the data, store the scrollTop-property and after that, restore it.

Like so:

```
var oldScrollTop = div.scrollTop;
div.innerHTML = "new content";
div.scrollTop = oldScrollTop;
```

Comment: Good idea.  In my situation it's a little tricky since the number of records being returned on refresh is not guaranteed to be the same i.e. the scrollbar may need to be a different # pixels from the top.

I discovered that using on-page anchors does in fact work in IE just as with Firefox, except that they cannot link to <tr> elements.  I moved the unique row IDs to the first <td> within each row and it worked.